# codeigniter how to update outward_frequency field with iterated value every time it saves

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following is my model, and the default value for `outward_frequency` is `0`. I need to make `outward_frequency` field iterated every time item is outwarded from 1 to infinity

```
function outward_item($request_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->set('outward_frequency', 'outward_frequency+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('request_id', $request_id);
    $this->db->update('requests', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change, hope this will help you:

```
function outward_item($request_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->set('outward_frequency', '`outward_frequency`+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('request_id', $request_id);
    $this->db->update('requests', $data);
}
```

Comment: do you think this one is working, the only thing you added is quotation mark

Comment: I believe this will work, because i used it many a times in my various projects.